# How to extend a union type with an additional property?

Tags: flowtype

I'm using [disjoint union types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) to represent events, as is [recommended for Redux-like actions](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-actions). Generally this is working well, but in some parts of my app, events have an additional timestamp field. How do I annotate the type of a timestamped event without duplicating something?

I tried using [intersection types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/#toc-intersections-of-object-types) to merge the additional required property, but the following fails:

```
/* @flow */

export type EvtA = {type: 'A', prop1: string};
export type EvtB = {type: 'B', prop2: string};

export type Event =
  | EvtA
  | EvtB;

type Timestamped = { timestamp: number };

type TSEvent = Event & Timestamped;
function show(event : TSEvent) {
  console.log(event.timestamp);
//  let event = ((e: any): Event);
  if (event.type === 'A') {
    console.log(event.prop1);
  }
}
```

Error (on http://flow.org/try):

```
 function show(event : TSEvent) {
                          ^ all branches are incompatible: Either property `prop1` is missing in `EvtB` [1] but exists in `EvtA` [2]. Or property `prop1` is missing in `Timestamped` [3] but exists in `EvtA` [2]. Or property `prop2` is missing in `EvtA` [1] but exists in `EvtB` [4]. Or property `prop2` is missing in `Timestamped` [3] but exists in `EvtB` [4].
References:
12: type TSEvent = Event & Timestamped;
                   ^ [1]
7:   | EvtA       ^ [2]
12: type TSEvent = Event & Timestamped;
                           ^ [3]
8:   | EvtB;
       ^ [4]
17:     console.log(event.prop1);
                    ^ Cannot get `event.prop1` because: Either property `prop1` is missing in `EvtB` [1]. Or property `prop1` is missing in `Timestamped` [2].
References:
12: type TSEvent = Event & Timestamped;
                   ^ [1]
12: type TSEvent = Event & Timestamped;
                           ^ [2]
```

The commented-out typecast is my current hacky workaround.

(Yes, perhaps the cleaner approach would have been `type LogEntry = { event: Event, timestamp: number }`, but that requires changing a lot of other code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is an object spread:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAUQDdCBBMAXjAG8yKAuMAcnp4A0YHPjg4AjNwDOhfAEsAdgHMAvgG5MuAsQ6VahAELM2u7jwODhonACZpsxao2a8REuT00MC4k1RgwAB9qOnp-IJDDZ10wABU5AFsMGQBDBIoAE2N2ROTCNJxuBQBXBIAjDHwwdXQY2IBlWm8GbPCAOg79egF2jvik1PSMDJ6agNRgYDjGrx9GBUQwAAsUqXcuCanWETFxAH5uBLksYaFCXMGcA7Ajk5H1jGvb4ZV0KGKFAGNzuAUwKSWiAAFBhZsRuA0mnMAJRscKfX5SOAwDBteBKEFgtrnAb5dLQjQBSYBFHEUHNYxAkHcFIKUjQ7hQwgE8JyKBgTHNbEeZhMFh8Hiw1jhAIIhRIlFouAY8k+No7CQsgKvFRAA))

```
/* @flow */

export type EvtA = {type: 'A', prop1: string};
export type EvtB = {type: 'B', prop2: string};

export type Event =
  | EvtA
  | EvtB;

type Timestamped = {timestamp: number };

type TSEventA = {
  ...EvtA,
  ...Timestamped,
};

// TSEventA now has type:
// {prop1?: mixed, timestamp?: mixed, type?: mixed}

function show(event : TSEventA) {
  console.log(event.timestamp);
  //  let event = ((e: any): Event);
  if (event.type === 'A') {
    console.log(event.prop1);
  }
}
```

You can retain all the type information by spreading [exact objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types):

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4egKmABAzAbA9gd2BMAoDpgFMAeADogE4AuwZAnobsAKIBuZAgsALzADeAPtbQC5gAchbCANMEIlEhAIxCAzmRIBLAHYBzHgF8A3NlAFi5SjTpMyAIQ7c+5ocKsSpMwgCYlKjdv1YcxqQU-BaMuOoU7IY4PAzMLNGgsZZWBokhwAAqqgC2uMoAhjm0ACa2vGS5+WRFhELqAK45AEa4JLppOBmZAMpM4ZHciSAAdGP9EeLDwGMj2XmFxbgliX6JYGBZfWERwOoowAAWBYrADeqqiOpmguubXNKynsDKalqSlQs1xfVNrSQfBzAABEVmBOjuwFiDzcChe3nelCqizqez+bUBghBLHB-lAsHOAGNKlcXocUAAKXA7ChCXoTMgASiGOBAhKuikQ8FwIyQmipNJGn2qtUZBlZwFUsGAAoGQvMHHYnFEwmZXGmbI5XJ5fIpKsk1Llj3kYumOjw8EUdClMsNEXltEVyucao1wHZ6k53N5iH5ThcdrII2N7lNEohOB0QA))

```
/* @flow */

export type EvtA = {|type: 'A', prop1: string|};
export type EvtB = {|type: 'B', prop2: string|};

export type Event =
  | EvtA
  | EvtB;

type Timestamped = {|timestamp: number|};

type TSEvent = {
  ...Event,
  ...Timestamped
};

// TSEvent now has union type:
// {prop2: string, timestamp: number, type: "B"}
// | {prop1: string, timestamp: number, type: "A"}

function show(event : TSEvent) {
  console.log(event.timestamp);
  if (event.type === 'A') {
    console.log('A', event.prop1);
  } else if (event.type === 'B') {
    console.log('B', event.prop2);
  }
}
```

Comment: `show` should be able to take any event and refine based on its type flag, so having it only take a timestamped `EvtA` missed the point. But [spreading worked](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAUQDdCBBMAXjAG8AfMigLjAHJ6fADRgc+ODgCMvAM6F8ASwB2Ac3YBfANyZcBYl0q1CAIWZtO5DLz7Hho8TgBMs+crVb02PERKXqNDCViJlQwMHZ-BlDwyONtVAMwABUFAFsMOQBDVIoAEzMOQjSMwmycXiUAV1SAIwx8DXjEpIBlWkDgtmiAOl72oKEe3pT0rJyMXNQPVChKpQBjIrglMBkAC0QACgwAoLBeVv7CAEousPnlmTgYDG74FW3dwm6i0dKc4+0whSgwR46Xn4mMD+IJTqxoudLtdbvdNgI7DsAWIJJJPtF1GAMDAZJQfn8kUFARRmCCbHxwZCwBclFcbnc4A9ySJCc8UU50WF1FMgA)!